# Can I get the First and Last Transaction in a single query in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to get the First Receipt Number and the Last Receipt Number for a particular day. Is there a way to get it in one statement? I can get it using 2 statements like so:

```
cnn.Open()
query = "select top 1(invoice) from invoice_tbl where transaction_date = @transaction_date order by invoice Desc"
cmd = new sqlCommand(query,cnn)
.......
```

and

```
cnn.Open()
query = "select top 1(invoice) from invoice_tbl where transaction_date = @transaction_date order by invoice Asc"
cmd = new sqlCommand(query,cnn)
.......
```

Can I get booth values in a single statement and place it in a variable so that I can place it on two labels separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
(select top 1(invoice) 
from invoice_tbl 
where transaction_date = @transaction_date order by invoice Desc) as last_inv ,
(select top 1(invoice) 
from invoice_tbl 
where transaction_date = @transaction_date order by invoice Asc) as First_inv
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be something like.....

```
SELECT invoice
FROM (
select   invoice
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by invoice DESC) Last_Invc
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by invoice ASC ) First_Invc
from invoice_tbl 
where transaction_date = @transaction_date 
) t
WHERE Last_Invc = 1
   OR First_Invc = 1
```

Comment: Yup. I think that would work as well. But I always want to keep it simple and easy to understand just by reading it.